# MSAL4J API with Azure AD B2C - pure JSP/Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Is there any example of working with Microsoft Authentication Library for Java using an application without Spring-Boot?. I'm working on a legacy application and it doesn't use Spring-Boot, it uses servlet with jsp. I only want to put authentication in this application using AD B2C service.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on GitHub:

[Microsoft GitHub - msal-b2c-web-sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-msal-java-samples/tree/4ab332c291b4f462635a370571cfcf8ed0532799/3-java-servlet-web-app)